# C# Displaying text box (present in the list view) value in a message box (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a list view in which each row contains 5 entries. The list box looks like this:

[image: ![]

I need to store (display) the name of variable and the value present in "Physical value" column text box when i press OK button. For e.g. if i enter 45 in the physical value text box (only one row at a time) then the name of the variable and value "45" should be stored (displayed). I am able to retrieve the name of the variables but not the value of the text box.

My try:

This code will populate the list view with variables and bind it to the properties.

```
 public void Populatevariables(IList<string> variables)
    {
        int rowcount = 0;
        dataGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        dataGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

        RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
        rd.Height = new GridLength();
        dataGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
        dataGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        dataGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        Label t1 = new Label();
        t1.Content = "Variables";
        Grid.SetColumn(t1, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(t1, rowcount);
        dataGrid.Children.Add(t1);



        ListView VrblPopulateList = new ListView();

        GridView g1 = new GridView();

        g1.AllowsColumnReorder = true;

        //l1.View = g1;
        GridViewColumn g2 = new GridViewColumn();
        g2.Header = "Name";
        g2.Width = 200;
        g2.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Name");
        g1.Columns.Add(g2);

        GridViewColumn g5 = new GridViewColumn();
        g5.Header = "DataType";
        g5.Width = 200;
        g5.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("DataType");
        g1.Columns.Add(g5);

        GridViewColumn g3 = new GridViewColumn();
        g3.Header = "Current Value";
        g3.Width = 200;

        DataTemplate dt1 = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory FF1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        FF1.SetBinding(TextBox.BindingGroupProperty, new Binding("Current_Value"));
        FF1.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, Height = 30);
        FF1.SetValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, Width = 150);
        dt1.VisualTree = FF1;
        g3.CellTemplate = dt1;


        g1.Columns.Add(g3);

        GridViewColumn g6 = new GridViewColumn();
        g6.Header = "Physical Value";
        g6.Width = 200;

        DataTemplate dt2 = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory FF2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        FF2.SetBinding(TextBox.BindingGroupProperty, new Binding("Physical_Value"));
        //FF2.AddHandler(TextBox.TextChangedEvent, txtchanged, true);
        FF2.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, Height = 30);
        FF2.SetValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, Width = 150);
        dt2.VisualTree = FF2;
        g6.CellTemplate = dt2;


        g1.Columns.Add(g6);


        GridViewColumn g4 = new GridViewColumn();
        g4.Header = "Action";
        g4.Width = 200;

        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory FF = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
        FF.SetBinding(Button.BindingGroupProperty, new Binding("ToDo"));
        FF.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty,Height = 30);
        FF.SetValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, Width = 150);
        FF.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Button.ContentProperty,"OK");
        FF.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(b1_click));
        dt.VisualTree = FF;           
        g4.CellTemplate = dt;

        g1.Columns.Add(g4);
        VrblPopulateList.View = g1;


        Grid.SetRow(VrblPopulateList, rowcount + 1);
        dataGrid.Children.Add(VrblPopulateList);


        for (int i = 0; i < variables.Count; i++)
        {
            Label lb1 = new Label();
            lb1.Content = variables[i].Name;

            Label lb2 = new Label();
            lb2.Name = variables[i].datatype;

            DataTemplate dd = new DataTemplate();
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();

            tb.Name = "TextBox" + i.ToString();
            Button b1 = new Button();



            VrblPopulateList.Items.Add(new User() { Name = lb1.Content, DataType = lb2.Name, Current_Value = tb, Physical_Value = tb, ToDo = b1 });





        }



    }
```

This code defines the property which is bind while populating:

```
 public class User
   {
       public object Name { get; set; }

       public string DataType { get; set; }

       public Control Current_Value
       {
           get;

           set;

       }

       public Control Physical_Value
       {
           get;

           set;

       }

       public Control ToDo { get; set; }

   }
```

**At last this code will retrieve all the items when button is clicked.**

```
 private void b1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        User item = (User)((Button)sender).DataContext;

        TextBox t = (TextBox)item.Physical_Value;

        MessageBox.Show(item.Name.ToString() + t.Text);



    }
```

The text box value is always empty. I know it can be solved by adding handler to "text changed" event while populating. But i dont know how to do it. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the binding to `PropertyChanged` and modifying your User model to instead of having Physical_Value property of Control but as string (which you would bound to the Text property of the textbox in the datatemplate) ?

Comment: Did you mean this?     FF2.SetBinding(TextBox.BindingGroupProperty, new Binding("Physical_Value") { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

Comment: Yes, but you should also change your model. Your model should not contain controls.. It should contain values that controls in your xaml need to use. I would suggest you would do something like in [this article](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/). This would make your code so much more readable.

Comment: I have changed my user model. But the problem is the value of text box is dynamic and should be fetched during run time. The example which you gave has static entries which is not the case with me. Can you please give some similar code examples ?

Comment: @Ponas Justas: Thanks:)  I did the changes accordingly and it worked. :)

Comment: Glad to hear you managed to do this. I was about to write a small code sample .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @Ponas Justas i have to do following changes in my code:

1. Set the **UpdateSourceTrigger** property of the text box.
2. Change the user model accordingly.

After doing above changes my code looks like:

```
 FF2.SetBinding(TextBox.BindingGroupProperty, new Binding("Physical_Value"));
 FF2.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("PhysicalValueTxtChanged") { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
```

**User Model**

```
public class User
   {
       public object Name { get; set; }

       public string DataType { get; set; }

       public Control Current_Value
       {
           get;

           set;

       }
       public string _PhysicalValueTxtChanged = null;
       public string PhysicalValueTxtChanged
       {
           get { return _PhysicalValueTxtChanged; }

           set
           {
               _PhysicalValueTxtChanged = value;
           }

       }

       public Control ToDo { get; set; }

   }
```

After doing that the text in the text box can be easily stored by just modifying like this:

```
 private void b1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        User item = (User)((Button)sender).DataContext;

        string txt = item.PhysicalValueTxtChanged;

        MessageBox.Show(item.Name.ToString() + txt);


    }
```

Thanks a lot Ponas Justas.

Comment: Dont forget to do the same for ToDo and Current_Value properties. And you did not have to rename the PhysicalValue property to PhysicalValueTxtChanged. Anyway i would strongly suggest you would do some reading about wpf xaml and bindings. You should move more of your code from code behind to xaml and do the bindings in xaml.
Anyway glad to have helped

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :). I will do some more reading. I am just one month old in wpf and bindings. :(

Comment: Thats fine. After you will gain some general knowledge about wpf and how to properly work with it, you can also read about prism and how you can use it in your wpf applications. Here is the [Documentation of Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Documentation) and of course some [samples](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf)

Comment: @PonasJustas Can you please answer my one more question. Here is the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696178/how-to-display-items-in-data-grid-view-based-on-many-checkbox-selection-in-wpf)