# How to Display items in data grid view based on many checkbox selection in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have developed a UI which looks as follows:
[image]

I want to display the items in the data grid on the basis of selected checkboxes.

**Current Scenario:**
Right now with my code always the items present in my latest checkbox selected file is getting displayed. For e.g. if i have selected 1st checkbox then the items present in first file is correctly displayed and similarly if i have selected 2nd checkbox then items from 2nd file is getting displayed.

**Required Usecase** (Not Able to do this)
If both the checkboxes are selected then items from both the files should be displayed. Secondly, if i deselct one checkbox then items from that file should not be displayed. I mean the items should be updated dynamically on the basis of checkbox selection.

**My Try**

```
FrameworkElementFactory FF = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));

FF.SetBinding(CheckBox.BindingGroupProperty, new Binding("Index"));
FF.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("FileSelected") { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
FF.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
for (int i = 0; i < Resultnew.Count; i++)
{
    var Dgrh = new DataGridRowHelper() { File_Name = lb1.Content, Index = i };
    Dgrh.ThrowFileSlctdEvent += (sender1, args) => {items = PopulateVariables(Resultnew[Dgrh.File_Name.ToString()]); DataGrid.ItemsSource = items; };
    Dgrh.ThrowFileNotSlctdEvent += (sender2, args) => { };
    A2lFilesPopulateList.Items.Add(Dgrh);
}
```

**Definitions**

```
ObservableCollection<DataGridRowHelper> items = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRowHelper>();
private Dictionary<String, ParsedResult> Resultnew = new Dictionary<String, ParsedResult>();
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args); //Defined in DataGridrowhelperClass
public event EventHandler ThrowFileSlctdEvent = delegate { }; //Defined in DataGridrowhelperClass
    public event EventHandler ThrowFileNotSlctdEvent = delegate { }; //Defined in DataGridrowhelperClass
```

**One Possible Solution**
Make a "OK" button. After selecting checkboxes user have to click on OK button everytime. Send the selected checkbox as list and display the files accordingly. (I have implemented this successfully but i dont want this solution as it is not user friendly).

Please suggest me how to implement **"Required UseCase"**

Comment: Okay, please stop using code behind for bindings and other UI stuff.. xaml is for that. Now it is just a pain to read. Anyway the problem why only the last selected file is displayed in the datagrid is because you are overwriting ItemsSource property of the datagrid when ThrowFileSlctdEvent event is fired. You need to use one object of type ObservableCollection<DataGridRowHelper> (which is bound to the datagrid) and add and remove items from it according to the file selection.

Comment: ItemsSource of the datagrid just has to be assigned once and not each time when ThrowFileSlctdEvent is fired. When the ThrowFileSlctdEvent event is fired you have to just modify the observableCollection items by ading them or removing. The UI will get automatically updated when that collection gets changed.

Comment: Thanks :) The reason of using code bindings is that in my project everything is dynamic binding. Can i use dynamic binding in XAML too?

Comment: I understood the problem. Regarding the solution can you please show how to modify the datagrid part?

Comment: @PonasJustas Where i have to set the item source (DataGrid.Itemssource = items)? During Initialization of the component or somewhere else?

Comment: @PonasJustas I have tried many things but all in vain. The collection is not getting updated. Firstly, i removed the "Datagrid.Itemssource = items" from the event handler and put it inside the constructor of main class. But when i select the checkbox then no data is being displayed. Secondly, i have bound the item source to an object of ObservableCollection<DataGridRowHelper> in XAML. But then also the data was not populating. Note: i am adding data to collection only when the check box is selected in my code. Do i need to change that?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic binding? are you chaning the bound property type or just the value? if only the value of the property then you should do the binding in xaml. If you are chaning the type of the bound property then you cna do that in xaml but you would need to use datatemplateselector. You did the right thing to add the binding of itemssource to constructor. When you did that, did you modify the event handler to update the collection?

Comment: @PonasJustas Do you mean that i need to update this Dgrh.ThrowFileSlctdEvent += (sender1, args) => { items = PopulateCalibrations(Resultnew[Dgrh.A2lFile_Name.ToString()]); }; ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114212/discussion-between-ponas-justas-and-sats).